# How to progammatically pass the callable to gunicorn instead of arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, gunicorn

I have the following implementation to spin up a web app using gunicorn

```py
@click.command("run_app", help="starts application in gunicorn")
def run_uwsgi():
    """
    Runs the project in gunicorn
    """

    import sys

    sys.argv = ["--gunicorn"]

    sys.argv.append("-b 0.0.0.0:5000")
    sys.argv.append("myapp.wsgi:application")

    WSGIApplication(usage="%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()
```

This will spin up the app using gunicorn, as per the requirement  how to spin this up without using arguments? Is there a way to assign sys.argv values to the gunicorn ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to post the solution which I have worked out

```
@click.command("uwsgi", help="starts application in gunicorn")
def run_uwsgi():
    """
    Runs the project in gunicorn
    """
    from gunicorn.app.base import Application

    import sys

    class MyApplication(Application):
        """
        Bypasses the class `WSGIApplication` and made it 
        independent from command line arguments
        """
        def init(self, parser, opts, args):

            self.cfg.set("default_proc_name", args[0])

            # Added this to ensure the application integrity
            self.app_uri = "myapp.wsgi:application"

        def load_wsgiapp(self):
            # This would do the trick
            # returns application callable
            return application

        def load(self):
            return self.load_wsgiapp()

    sys.argv = ["--gunicorn"]

    sys.argv.append(f"-b {os.environ['APP_HOST']}:{os.environ['APP_PORT']}")

    # Throws an error if this is missing.
    sys.argv.append("myapp.wsgi:application")

    MyApplication(usage="%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()
```

I have directly returning the callable from

```
def load_wsgiapp(self):
    # This would do the trick
    # returns application callable
    return application
```

`wsgi.py`

```
application = main.create_app()
```

But still needed to pass a command line argument for the module, other wise it throws an error.
If you are using Nuitka to bundle your application you can spin it up and use with gunicorn.